# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deep')

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am develop a google chrome extension using vue3 + typescript. I use `v-link` like this in the vue3 template like this:

```
<li>
   <a v-link="{name:'about',activeClass:'active'}">About</a>
</li>
```

when run this code in the app, shows error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deep')
    at withDirectives (option.js:10888:17)
    at Proxy.render (option.js:17637:72)
    at renderComponentRoot (option.js:8084:44)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (option.js:12178:57)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (option.js:6038:25)
    at setupRenderEffect (option.js:12304:9)
    at mountComponent (option.js:12087:9)
    at processComponent (option.js:12045:17)
    at patch (option.js:11646:21)
    at render (option.js:12789:13)
```

the `vue-router` version is `"vue-router": "^4.0.12"`, why did this happen? what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

in your main.ts use like this "const app = createApp(App);app.directive(xxx) ;app.mount('#app');"

when i use the code" const app = createApp(App) ; app.directive(xxx) ;createApp(App).mount('#app')". error  happend

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think it is related with the v-link attribute. I have the same issue with v-t